# Identify which input field trigger ng-change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chromium

I have 2 input fields and I prefer to have one `ng-change` function to store their values in the `chrome.storage.local` when either of these change:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="mod1" ng-change="inputChange()" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 250 }">
<input type="text" ng-model="mod2" ng-change="inputChange()" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 250 }">
```

Function in the controller is similar to this:

```
$scope.mod1 = "";
$scope.mod2 = "";
$scope.inputChange = function(data) {
  chrome.storage.local.set({
    $scope.model.id : data,
  }, function() {
    console.log("success!");
  });
}
```

Can't figure out how to obtain changed model's id. Other suggestions to persist form data on change?

***EDIT***

After multiple comments (thank you) I've ended up with the following ([jsbin](https://jsbin.com/temonerula/edit?html,js,console,output)):

```js
var app = angular.module('example', []);

app.controller('example', ["$scope", "$log",
  function($scope, $log) {

    $scope.form = {
      form_fields: ["mod1", "mod2", "mod3"],
      module: {
        "mod1": null,
        "mod2": null,
        "mod3": null,
      },
      error: {
        "mod1": false,
        "mod2": false,
        "mod3": false,
      },
      field_attr: {
        "mod1": {
          type: "text",
          placeh: "Module-1 Input",
        },
        "mod2": {
          type: "password",
          placeh: "Module-2 Input",
        },
        "mod3": {
          type: "text",
          placeh: "Module-3 Input",
        },
      }
    };

    $scope.inputChange = function(modID) {
      $log.warn("Module: " + modID + "; value: " + $scope.form.module[modID]);
    };

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="example" ng-controller="example">
  <div id="form-gen" ng-repeat="field in form.form_fields">
    <input type="{{form.field_attr[field].type}}" id="{{field}}-in" placeholder="{{form.field_attr[field].placeh}}" ng-model="form.module[field]" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" ng-change="inputChange(field)">
  </div>
</body>
```

Is there anything that still can be improved?

Comment: your `inputChange` function appears to be expecting an object, yet you are trying to use it on an input text field which could only have a string primitive as it's model.  This function doesn't appear as though it will work with this binding.

Comment: The only thing I need is to identify which model has triggered my `inputChange` function. Please see updated controller code sample.

Comment: this is still not making sense.  `mod1` is a string, how does that relate to some separate `model` object with an `id` property and a `data` property?

Comment: This is more like a pseudo code, so please see it that way. I assumed that there's a way to extract model id from the scope, that's why I put it this way.

Comment: but you still haven't really explained **what `mod1` is**.  a string can't have an id. is it more like `ng-model="mod1.data"`?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes this is just a basic string container. Please see updated controller code sample.

Comment: ok, then in that case, you don't have anything at all with an id property, which is what I already said in my first comment.  You keep saying you are looking for the changed model's id, but the changed model is a string, it doesn't have an id.

Comment: I do not need `id` property. Like I said, I just want to **identify which input field triggered** `inputChange`. So far I only get it's value, which is not good enough.

Comment: there isn't anything to differentiate those input boxes except the `ng-model`, and since that is a string, it's value is all you have to work with.

Comment: So my only option is to declare a separate function for each input field?

Comment: no... the better option is to use an object rather than a primitive.  i.e. if your model were `ng-model="mod1.data"` and you used `ng-change="inputChange(mod1)"`, a `function(model)` can receive that `model` object and work with it.  Objects are passed by reference, primitives are passed by value.

Comment: incidentally, in angular, you should always be thinking about the data you are passing around, not the elements (i.e. the input) that is being used to manipulate the data.  you don't really care about which input it is, you care about which piece of data it is so that you can store it and retrieve it later and work with it in a consistent manner.

Comment: Thank you, that's all I needed to know

Comment: well, what you want to do is as easy as `...ng-model="mod1" ng-change="inputChange('first')"...` and `...ng-model="mod2" ng-change="inputChange('second')"...`.

Comment: on another note, the way you have presented your question doesn't help you though - the code snippet you provided makes it very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `$event` into your on-change function.
Then in your controller you can do $event.target to find the html element that changed.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="mod1" ng-change="inputChange($event)" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 250 }">
<input type="text" ng-model="mod2" ng-change="inputChange($event)" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 250 }">


$scope.inputChange = function($event) {
  var changedInput = $event.target;
}
```

Sorry, this doesn't work for `ng-change`. `ng-change` is a directive and not an event handler. If you were to use `ng-keypress` it would work.

Alternatively you could use a `watch` for this.

```
  $scope.$watch('mod1', function(newMod, oldMod){
    if(newMod == oldMod) return;

    console.log('mod1 changed!');
  });

  $scope.$watch('mod2', function(newMod, oldMod){
    if(newMod == oldMod) return;

    console.log('mod2 changed!');
  });
```

Examples: https://jsbin.com/teparofogi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks for the lovely demo, but my primary goal of asking this question was to find a way to avoid boilerplate. With `$scope.$watch` it's not possible in this particular context, as these functions would do the exact same job - take a value and put in the local storage bucket. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass this to `on-change` function and get the changed input element by using the below snippet :

```
$scope.inputChange = function(e) {
   var changedInput = e.target; //you can access further prop too       
}
```